# Flow Builder - Screen

Tags: flow-builder

How to make text field appear after a certain checkbox has been ticked?
Scenario example:
Order field may or may not be required. (checkbox for this) 
If the checkbox is ticked, user has to input the Order name in a text field.
If checkbox is not ticked, field should be hidden from view.
Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Take alook at this [release note](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fieldrules.htm)

If it didn't help, you'll have to use a lightning-component (Or LWC) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Values/Variables/Choices in the same Flow screen was released in spring '17

You can check some  [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fieldrules.htm)

I think you will have to enable Lightning runtime in the setup via Process Automation Settings

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below there are conditions (1) and field settings (2) while defining Field Rules.

- The conditions specify when to execute the rule.
- The field settings let you control whether the field is visible, hidden, required, or optional.​

Selecting Call Me checkbox displays Phone field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone seeing this now:
Currently (Oct 2023) you can easily do this for a Display Text element (and many others) by adjusting the settings of the "Set Component Visibility" to `checkbox_field__c = true` in the formula and customizing your error message.